# Authenticate user from other application and then come back to our application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the scenario... I have been asked to develop an application which authenticate a user from compani's loginpage. Now the thing is application will work on intranet i can authenticate user through domain but how can i authenticate a user from some others web application(login page)...the id and the password of that login page would be same as that of domain username and password in intranet ...
How i would go to another applications login page and after successful login come back to my application's after login page.

I am trying to build this in c#.

Comment: Question is to general. Maybe look into single sign on access control? Or run a server application in your intranet that is accessible through a secure web connection, handling the authentication requests.

Comment: @Klein isnt this possible using webconfig files in two separate folders of the solution?.